# Prisma migration skips insert

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, prisma

I'm using Prisma as an ORM for my NodeJS project.
So far I have one initial migration, which creates the basic DB schema.
Now I want to add a new feature, so I need to extend and modify my schema.

My goal is to add a new table, and a field to an existing table that's a foreign key referencing this new table.
What I would logically do with MySQL would be to create the table, insert the row that needs to be referenced:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    `created_at` DATETIME(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
    `updated_at` DATETIME(3) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `new_table`
(`id`, `title`, `description`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
(1, 'Foo', 'Bar', '2022-07-21 12:35:44.514', '2022-07-21 12:35:44.513');
```

and then add the column and the constraint to the other table:

```
ALTER TABLE `old_table` ADD COLUMN `new_table_id` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;

ALTER TABLE `old_table` ADD CONSTRAINT `old_table_new_table_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`new_table_id`) REFERENCES `old_table`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

The problem is that, when I run `npx prisma db push`, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`#sql-1_c`, CONSTRAINT `old_table_new_table_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`new_table_id`) REFERENCES `old_table` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

When I then check the DB after this command fails, I can see that I have the `new_table` in the DB, but it's *empty*, which causes the error.
Meanwhile, the rows on `old_table` also have the new `new_table_id` column correctly added, with value 1.

Why does `npx prisma db push` execute every other command, **but not the `INSERT`**?
And how can I change the migrations, so that I can achieve what I need (which seems like pretty easy and standard SQL fare to me)?

I am aware of `npx prisma db seed`, and in fact I do have a seeds file, but that command should be executed *after* the migrations have run, so while I added an entry for the `new_table` with that row, that doesn't really help me.

Answer (score -3):

1. You should need to create table in your db.
   And never touch your schema.prisma file & `prisma migrate`
2. After Create or Modifying table in your db

```
    npx prisma db pull
    npx prisma generate
```

3. And your db migrating your schema.prisma
   after you can use prisma

Comment: What? No, this is not how I'm working. I'm following the [documented workflow](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate), so I'm working schema-first, editing my `prisma.schema` file and then running `prisma migrate dev` and `prisma migrate deploy`. Sorry but this answer is completely wrong, and doesn't even address my main concern about the `INSERT` statement.